# Determine the Mobius transform from $\infty$ to $0$, $0$ to $-i$ and $i$ to $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, mobius-transformation

Determine the Mobius transform from $\infty$ to $0$,  $0$ to $-i$ and $i$ to $\infty$

I have done the following:

1)
$$\lim \limits_{z\to \infty} \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=0$$
$$\iff \lim_{z\to 0} \frac{a\frac{1}{z} + b}{c\frac{1}{z}+d}$$
$$=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{a+bz}{c+dz}\implies \frac ac=0\implies a=0$$

2) $$\frac bd = -i \implies b=-id$$

3) $$\lim_{z\to i} \frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\infty$$
$$\iff \lim_{z\to i} \frac{cz+d}{az+b}=0$$
$$=\lim_{z\to i} \frac{cz+d}{b} \implies ci+d=0\implies ci=-d$$

Hence $a=0,b=b,c=-b,d=bi$

And I believe we obtain $$T(z) = \frac{b}{-bz+bi} = \frac{1}{-z+i}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: A typo in your last equality. It should be ${1\over -z+i}$. Other than that it is correct

Comment: @marwalix Thanks!

Comment: Just evaluate it and remember that $-i=\frac{1}{i}$!